# How to configure orm.xml entity mapping file with kundera?

Tags: java, orm, kundera, oracle-nosql

I am using kundera version 2.13. I am exploring to use Kundera with Oracle NOSQL db.
How do I configure Kundera to use my custom xml mapping file that is generated during runtime?
Due to design I can't use annotation for entities(they are also generated runtime).
So, I have to use XML mapping. But all examples shows only annotation.
For eclipselink parameter "eclipselink.metadata-source.xml.file" can be configured runtime.

Thanks
Gopi

Answer (score 0):

found the answer. at moment they don't support xml mapping.
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/630